# Use batchjob to open Excel File

Tags: excel, batch-file, job-scheduling

I'm trying to open an Excel File using a batchjob, but Windows isn't having it. I'm new at batchjobs so I'm largely cluess and have been trying to figure it out using oneline tips. However, I don't see what I'm doing differently than some of the examples that I've found.

Can anyone point out **why this doesn't work** to me?

```
@echo off
cls
start /d C:\Users\Admin\Gotti_Notes%20vENO0.3.xlsm
```

Also, since I'm asking, **how can I set the exact time for this to run?** Scheduled tasks in windows I assume. Correct?

I get no error message... it seems to run, but simply doesn't do anything.

The point of all of this is to open the file at a specified time (at night) and have excel automatically run a vba macro i wrote (which it would do using the "open" command).

UPDATE & SOLUTION:

```
@echo off
cls
call C:\Users\Admin\Notes.xlsm
echo on
```

I had to change the name in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you should be doing something like

```
C:\path\to\excel C:\Users\Admin\Gotti_Notes%20vENO0.3.xlsm
```

instead. As [this SuperUser question notes](https://superuser.com/q/640359/195567), the command might look more like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" "C:\Users\Admin\Gotti_Notes%20vENO0.3.xlsm"
```

Side note: according to [this forum post](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/7840-how-start-excel-batch-file.html#post35897), if running a macro is your eventual goal, you can pass in the name of the macro with the `/m` flag. The poster says that this works with Word, but it might also work with Excel too.

Another side note: since you start the file with `@echo off`, you probably want to reverse this at the end with `echo on`; otherwise, after you run the script you won't have much of a prompt anymore.

Comment: @rohrl77 What about when you run it from the command line? Are you sure you have the right path to Excel's executable?

Comment: how do i run it from the command line? just use the directory file path?

Comment: just tried it from the commandline. had to adjust it to this C:\Users\Admin\"Gotti_Notes%20vENO0.3.xlsm"

Comment: It did work in the command line. However, afterwards in the batch file it didn't. But i have a solution thanks to your suggestions. Since it worked in the command line I thought maybe it might be because of the name. Umnlautes and spaces etc. So i changed the file name to "Notes.xlsm". That did it!

Answer (score 1):

the `/D`switch expects a path you set as working directory for the following command.

so, either (but uselessly)

```
start /d C:\Users\Admin C:\Users\Admin\Gotti_Notes%20vENO0.3.xlsm
```

or, more reasonably, since excel won't care about the path

```
start C:\Users\Admin\Gotti_Notes%20vENO0.3.xlsm
```

it is generally not necessary to call excel directly, if it starts when you double click the file in explorer, you can start it directly with `START`.